# How to write an Android share "plugin"?

Tags: android

I want to add my app into the share dialog in Android.
So that the user can select an image and "share" it with my application,
which would do some modifications before emailing it.

Any ideas how to where to start?

Comment: This seems to be duplicate to: [Android: how to add app to “Share via” list for camera picture][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669627/android-how-to-add-app-to-share-via-list-for-camera-picture

Answer (score 8):

You need to add an intent-filter to your application manifest, that allows it to handle objects of the MIME type `image/jpeg`.

Your application then receives a `Uri` to the file, and you can use that `Uri` to modify the image, as requested.

There's a lot about it on the Android developer site, including code samples:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html