# share my web page in the navigator lunch my application

Tags: android

When a open the navigator in my android than click menu than share page, a list of application appear. I want to have my application in that list.

Thanks for help

Comment: when i am in the navigator
and chose menu
than share page, than a list of application appear (facebook, twitter, Gmail, Skype,...)  
I want that my application appear in that list.  
How can i do this.  
I hope that i was clear  
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to add app to "Share via" list for camera picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669627/android-how-to-add-app-to-share-via-list-for-camera-picture)

Comment: yes i have to do an intent, it is that thanks.

Comment: but i don't know what i need to write in android:mimeType

    <data android:mimeType="?????" />

Comment: i don't know the type of date that my navigator will send!!!

Comment: Read the documentation on intent filters and try: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs

Comment: ok i got it :)
we must add this intent to manifest file:  
           <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

Thank you Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we must add this intent to manifest file:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```