# Send the latest picture taken to contact on whatsapp

Tags: android, facebook, android-camera, whatsapp

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
String text = "Text";
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (sendIntent != null) {
   sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "phone number"));
```

I am developing an app on Android in Eclipse that uses the camera default, the app should take a picture and send the picture to contact on whatsapp. I wanted to find out how I can send the last picture I took to a contact on whatsapp or mail or Facebook messenger.

Comment: Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                     sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                             String text = "Text";
                     sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                     if (sendIntent != null) {
                         sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
                         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "phone number"));

Comment: And now I want to add an image and I have no idea how

Comment: You should put your code in your question (click the edit link under your question) so that it can be properly formatted (use the `{}` button above the textbox).

Comment: sorry I am new here :)

Comment: Have you tried anything to start the camera and get back a picture? You should be able to find a tutorial to walk you through that process. Check out [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) to start. You might also find useful info on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can add share feature to you Android App.
Here goes the link : http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
...
</menu>
```

For Intent Share check this link:

[Android: how to add app to "Share via" list for camera picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669627/android-how-to-add-app-to-share-via-list-for-camera-picture)

Vrinda

Comment: hi @vrindamarfatia I don't want the user will choose the pic or choose the way to share , I want that the last pitcher taken will send to the contact on whatsapp

Comment: Okay so by default your app will share the snap to whatsapp that is taken most recently but do you need to select the contact?