# How to share a photo from gallery via My application

Tags: java, android

I just want my application make available for user to share a Photo from gallery using Share Via Intent Chooser. Additionally i want to perform basic action of my application just after choosing my application from share via Screen like watsapp. I don't have any idea about how to do. I searched around the Internet but i didn't get any satisfactory Solution. Infect i tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669627/android-how-to-add-app-to-share-via-list-for-camera-picture)

but unfortunately using this code in manifest my application is got disappeared from the Home Screen Application list in my device.

have a look over my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.myAppName"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" >

</uses-permission>

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--
 Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

 NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
       where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.app.myAppName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.app.myAppName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- Keeps the device on vibrating mode when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />



<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />

<application
    android:name="com.app.myAppName.TwitterApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.myAppName.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             -->

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" >
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" >
            </data>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <service
        android:name=".TimelinesService"
        android:label="Timelines Service" />

    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:label="NotificationService" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="tweeter"
                android:scheme="callback" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.app.myAppName.TweetsActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="TwitterLogin"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AddUser"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AddmyAppName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AddMemberTransparent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AddAFriendActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
        </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You application 'disappeared' because you commented these lines at SplashActivity section:

```
<!-- 
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
-->
```

as for share provider, which part are you stuck at?